# ChartJS - format datetime X axis when displaying data from MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, chart.js

I've adapted the example on this [site](https://www.dyclassroom.com/chartjs/chartjs-how-to-draw-line-graph-using-data-from-mysql-table-and-php) and have managed to get to a position where I can retrieve data from my MySql database and plot it ok, but I can't format the X axis as a date time axis correctly.

linegraph.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>ChartJS - LineGraph</title>
    <style>
      .chart-container {
        width: 1000px;
        height: auto;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
tst1
    <div class="chart-container">
      <canvas id="mycanvas"></canvas>
    </div>
    tst2
    <!-- javascript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Chart.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/linegraph.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

followersdata.php

```
<?php
//setting header to json
header('Content-Type: application/json');

//database
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');
define('DB_NAME', 'test');

//get connection
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

if(!$mysqli){
  die("Connection failed: " . $mysqli->error);
}

//query to get data from the table
$query = sprintf("SELECT reading_time, value1 FROM Sensor");

//execute query
$result = $mysqli->query($query);

//loop through the returned data
$data = array();
foreach ($result as $row) {
  $data[] = $row;
}

//free memory associated with result
$result->close();

//close connection
$mysqli->close();

//now print the data
print json_encode($data);
```

Example output of followersdata.php

```
[{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:38:48","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:39:18","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:39:49","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:40:19","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:40:49","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:41:19","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:41:49","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:42:19","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:42:49","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:43:19","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:43:50","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:44:20","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:44:50","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:45:20","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:45:50","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:46:21","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:46:51","value1":"1.10"},{"reading_time":"2020-02-24 22:47:21","value1":"1.10"},
```

linegraph.js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
url : "followersdata.php",

type : "GET",
success : function(data){
  console.log(data);

  var datetime = [];
  var value1  = [];
  //var twitter_follower = [];
  //var googleplus_follower = [];

  for(var i in data) {
    datetime.push(data[i].reading_time);
    value1.push(data[i].value1);
    //twitter_follower.push(data[i].twitter);
    //googleplus_follower.push(data[i].googleplus);
  }

  var chartdata = {
    labels: datetime,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Value1",
        fill: false,
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 0.75)",
        borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
        data: value1
      //},
      //{
      //  label: "twitter",
      //  fill: false,
      //  lineTension: 0.1,
      //  backgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 0.75)",
      //  borderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
      //  pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
      //  pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(29, 202, 255, 1)",
      //  data: twitter_follower
      //},
      //{
      //  label: "googleplus",
       // fill: false,
       // lineTension: 0.1,
       // backgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 0.75)",
       // borderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
       // pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
       // pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(211, 72, 54, 1)",
       // data: googleplus_follower
      }
    ],
    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
    animation: false,
        legend: {display: true  },
    scales:{xAxes: [{type: 'time',time: {unit: 'day',displayFormats: { 'day': 'MMM D' }}}]}
        }



 };



  var ctx = $("#mycanvas");

  var LineGraph = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: chartdata
  });
},
error : function(data) {

}
});
});
```

Resulting chart:
[image: Graph output]

I have tried using the options

```
options: {
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
animation: false,
    legend: {display: true  },
scales:{xAxes: [{type: 'time',time: {unit: 'day',displayFormats: { 'day': 'MMM D' }}}]}
    }
```

But it doesn't seem to format the axis as MMM D, or if I try hours, as hours etc.

Where am I going wrong? How can I get the Options to work as the legend doesn't display either.

Comment: You'll need to parse the dates as per your need either in `php` or at `front-end` before passing them as `options args`

Comment: How would I go about doing that? I have just tried 
 `datetime.push(Date.parse(data[i].reading_time));` in linegraph.js, and I can see the milliseconds in the graph now instead, so still no impact from the Options. Interestingly I have seen other examples where the input data is manually typed into a variable in the YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS  format without parse and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your code is that the chart `options` is nested inside the `data` object and actually ignored by Chart.js. Move it up to the next hierarchically level. Otherwise the `xAxis` definition looks just fine. There's also no need for explicitly parsing the date as one comment suggests since it is in a format that can be parsed by [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Alternatively to your `xAxis` definition, you can do it the following simpler way, the default [display format](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#display-formats) of `unit: 'day'` is actually what you're looking for (`'MMM D'`).

```
xAxes: [{
  type: 'time',
  time: {
    unit: 'day'
  }
}]
```

See below simplified example:

```js
const data = [
  {"reading_time":"2020-02-10 22:38:48","value1":"1.10"},
  {"reading_time":"2020-02-11 22:39:18","value1":"1.20"},
  {"reading_time":"2020-02-12 22:39:49","value1":"1.40"},
  {"reading_time":"2020-02-13 22:40:19","value1":"1.10"},
  {"reading_time":"2020-02-14 22:40:49","value1":"1.20"},
  {"reading_time":"2020-02-15 22:41:19","value1":"1.30"}
];

new Chart("mycanvas", {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: data.map(o => o.reading_time ),
    datasets: [{
      label: "Value1",
      fill: false,
      borderColor: "rgba(59, 89, 152, 1)",
      data: data.map(o => o.value1)
    }],
  },
  options: {
    scales: {
      xAxes: [{
        type: 'time',
        time: {
          unit: 'day'
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script> 
<canvas id="mycanvas" height="90"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this was very useful an allowed me to get what I wanted - much appreciated! One other thing I needed to do to get it working though (in case it is of use to anyone else), I needed to include `<script type="text/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>` before `<script type="text/javascript" src="Chart.js"></script>`.