# Chart.js - Format Date on X-Axis

Tags: chart.js

I am using chart.js v 3.9.1

My X-axis data is a date and time format like
2022-12-16 08:18:58

I'd like to be able to keep the full timestamp so that when I hover I can see all the details, but for display on the x-axis it would be good just to show the time part eg
08:18

I am trying to reduce the clutter a little and also reduce the amount of vertical space taken up by the labels on the x-axis.

Is it possible to format the x-axis like this and how would I do it?

At the moment my chart looks like:
[image: Sample chart with full timestamp format on x-axis]

Comment: At least show your code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format x-axis time scale values in Chart.js v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37061945/how-to-format-x-axis-time-scale-values-in-chart-js-v2)

Comment: That post helped with formatting once I got the real answer

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that I needed to use chart.bundle.js which apparently included moment.js, which helps with date/time parsing.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
```

I found this from [ChartJS - format datetime X axis when displaying data from MySql table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460274/chartjs-format-datetime-x-axis-when-displaying-data-from-mysql-table?rq=1)

The suggested post (comment to original question) then allowed me to control the formatting more precisely.

So I ended up with

[image]

```
scales: {
   xAxes: [{
      type: 'time',
      time: {
        unit: 'hour',
        displayFormats: {
           'hour': 'HH:MM',
        }
      }
   }],
},  // end scales
```

I could only find chart.bundle.js up to version 2.9.3 so I did try including chart.js and moment.js separately but could not get that to work. I will spend some more time on that problem, so that I can use later versions of chart.js. Although, moment.js appears to be "end-of-project" so I am not sure if there is an alternative and how that would work with chart.js - but that's a different problem

Thanks for the help

Update: Here's the chart.js v4.1.1 solution

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js@^4"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chartjs-adapter-date-fns/dist/chartjs-adapter-date-fns.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

And the scales configuration:

```
    scales: {
       x: {
          type: 'time',
          time: {
            unit: 'hour',
            displayFormats: {
               'hour': 'HH:MM',
            }
          }
       },
    },  // end scales
```